# Avoiding run my android app in background

Tags: android

I want to force exit my android app when it's going to background.So i use this code in my base Activity class.

```
@Override

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);         
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

But it's not working.Please help for resolving this.

Comment: why would you want to kill the background activity?

Comment: Do you want to close the the whole application or just the one activity ?

Comment: You cannot intercept Home. The OS won't let you as an anti hijacking measure. Not a good idea to call exit() either. Try the onStop() method in Basim's answer.

Comment: `System.exit(0)` is not a good way to exit. use `finish()`

Comment: i want to close the whole app

Comment: @user1621952 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon. Check the link and the answer by commonsware. You should leave that decision to the os.. Also chekc this in case you are looking for navigation flow http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do like this,

```
    @Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    finish();
}
```

This will override your Onstop method